# Paypal 'Buy Now' button not letting me dynamically set the price

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working with a "Buy Now" button from Paypal, and am stumped as to why it's not working (I've done it before).

I created a "Buy Now" button on Paypal, and unchecked "Save this button on Paypal" - so it's not hosted there.

I've got the `<form>` and the `<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="...">`. I also have an `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.00">` directly after that encrypted input, just to see if it will let me set the price.

And no luck - it always brings me to the page where users can type in their own price.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An encrypted button and input name=amount won't work together. You'll need to OR encrypted (incl. the amount) OR 'plain text'.
If you're using the online button creation tool, simply click "Remove code protection" to view the plain code, rather than the encrypted version.